# Companion object from library not available in app

Tags: android, kotlin

I build an Android Library (using Kotlin) and I have a class containing some constants.

```
class LibraryClass {
   companion object {
      @JVMStatic
      val MY_CONSTANT = "value"
   }
}
```

I generate an .aar file using the `assembleRelease` Gradle task, then I import the .aar file into another app.

The other app **also uses kotlin**, when I reference the constant inside the companion object, It can't find it.

```
if(myVariable == LibraryClass.MY_CONSTANT) {
   foo()
}
```

The IDE itself can't find it, it just says:
`Unresolved reference: MY_CONSTANT`

And when I use the IntelliJ decompiler, the constant is not there, not even using `LibraryClass.Companion`, it can't even find the reference to the Companion object.

How can I fix this?

Comment: AFAIK, `@JVMStatic` should be `@JvmStatic`. Beyond that, is anything in the library itself referring to `MY_CONSTANT`? If not, perhaps ProGuard/R8 is removing it. I'm uncertain as to what ProGuard/R8 does with AAR files, particularly Kotlin ones...

Comment: No, the library itself is not referencing the constant, those constant are expected to be used outside the library, so, I should tell R8 to ignore them?

Comment: That would be worth a try.

Comment: Did you solve this? @AlfredoBejarano

Comment: to be honest, I don't remember. Probably it was just an "invalidate project and restart"issue because of local .aar files. This was 2 years ago

Comment: I found that this was due to my proguard setup.
I fixed this by adding ```@Keep``` at the top of my companion object.